# Running Javascript from AJAX file

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs, jotform

I've been trying to get this to work for ages now, tried loads of SO question/answers but not geting very far.

I think I originally had 2 issues, one which hopefully I've resolved.

I've been using JotForm (the easy form creator that uses prototype). What I have is a facebook style menu ([AjaxFlagMenu](http://code.google.com/p/ajaxflagmenu/)) which creates a verticle ajax style menu that pulls in html snippets from external files (which in my case all have a Jotform form in there).

At the moment at the top of the 'main' page that contains the menu, I have:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.flagmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var Menu = $("#_Menu").AjaxFlagMenu({
    Caption:'Manage Profile',
    CaptionClass:'CaptionClass',
    onOutClass:'onOutClass',
    onOverClass:'onOverClass',
    onClickClass:'onClickClass',
    hscOutClass:'hscOutClass',
    hscClickClass:'hscClickClass',
    Loading_gif:'/images/loading.gif',
    ajaxContent:'ajaxContent'
    });
    //Basic
    Menu.add({
        Title:'Basic Info',
        onOutIcon:'/images/icon-vcard-c.png',
        onClickIcon:'/images/icon-vcard-d.png',
        HtmlSatusContent:'',
        url:'/instructor/pages/mp-basic.php',
        data:''
    });
    //Profile Picture
    Menu.add({
        Title:'Profile Picture',
        onOutIcon:'/images/icon-camera-c.png',
        onClickIcon:'/images/icon-camera-d.png',
        HtmlSatusContent:'',
        url:'/instructor/pages/mp-photo.php',
        data:''
    });
    //Pricing and Offers
    Menu.add({
        Title:'Pricing and Offers',
        onOutIcon:'/images/icon-pound-c.png',
        onClickIcon:'/images/icon-pound-d.png',
        HtmlSatusContent:'',
        url:'/instructor/pages/mp-pricing.php',
        data:''
    });
    //Services
    Menu.add({
        Title:'Services',
        onOutIcon:'/images/icon-services-c.png',
        onClickIcon:'/images/icon-services-d.png',
        HtmlSatusContent:'',
        url:'/instructor/pages/mp-services.php',
        data:''
    });
    //Bio and Additional
    Menu.add({
        Title:'Bio and Additional',
        onOutIcon:'/images/icon-bio-c.png',
        onClickIcon:'/images/icon-bio-d.png',
        HtmlSatusContent:'',
        url:'/instructor/pages/mp-bio.php',
        data:''
    });
    $("#_td").corner("4px");
});
</script>
<script src="/js/jotform/prototype.js?v=3.1.92" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jotform/protoplus.js?v=3.1.92" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jotform/protoplus-ui.js?v=3.1.92" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jotform/jotform.js?v=3.1.92" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jotform/calendarview.js?v=3.1.92" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What I then need to do, is when the menu item is clicked and loads the HTML from the other page, I need to run `JotForm.init();` to enable the JotForm validation functions. However, I don't even seem to be able to `alert("Hello World");` to work on the page that is called in.

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AjaxFlagMenu.js, at the line the ajax is executed:

```
//Ajax
var _XMLHTTPRequest = $.ajax({type: "GET",url:_url,data:_data });
```

Try adding `dataType: "html"` like this:

```
//Ajax
var _XMLHTTPRequest = $.ajax({type: "GET",url:_url,data:_data,dataType: "html" });
```

This wil evaluate the javascript you load via AJAX.

You will find more info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options

---

LATER EDIT

**The problem is that the AjaxFlagMenu doesn't evaluate the javascript from the ajax response!**

Comment: Thanks for that! Didn't change anything but looks as if it's a step in the right direction. Should the script on the external html file be in `$(document).ready(function()` or should it just be inside `<script></script>` tags?

Comment: Try executing something simple in the loaded html.. like <script>alert(1);</script> and see if it evals that.. what exactly does the html snippet that is loaded over ajax look like? I'm interested mostly in the javascript...

Comment: At the moment i've got <script>alert("Hello World");</script> but it's not coming up at the moment. I literally just need to call `JotForm.init();`. But would that also mean I need to include the JotForm js files in the external file itself or can I still include them in the main 'menu' page that the html is loaded into?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if you include it in the main page...why not try to call `JotForm.init();` as a  callback for the ajax request ( http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events )? `$.ajax({
  complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event JotForm.init();
   }
   // ......
 });
`

Comment: Still can't seem to get even an alert to call using the $.ajax function. Is it something that could be caused by the noConflict part on the main page?

Comment: Think i found the problem :) in the AjaxFlagMenu.js, after the ajax call, you can see a var being assigned the xhttprq (_XMLHTTPRequest), a few lines below, you have : `_XMLHTTPRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){...}, as you can see in that function, the content is loaded as plain text into the container and no jabascript is evaluated: `$("#"+Options.ajaxContent).html(_XMLHTTPRequest.responseText);`. Add `JotForm.init()` after the html is written and that should work

Comment: Ohh this looks promising. But, I got a bit lost with what you said I need to chance. Am I changing something in the js itself, or on my html pages?

Comment: :) search for `$("#"+Options.ajaxContent).html(_XMLHTTPRequest.responseText);` in the `AjaxFlagMenu.js`. The line above is followed by another 3 lines. After these lines, add `JotForm.init();` (or `alert(1)` to test)

Comment: That works perfectly! You deserve a medal lol. So now if I was to include an AJAX form updater, would that be added in the same way, or would I need to add that elsewhere?

Comment: It's pretty complicated...not sure it's worth to bother.. try undoing the changes to thejs file and replacing the ajax call with this: `var _XMLHTTPRequest = $.ajax({type: "GET",url:_url,data:_data , success: function(){JotForm.init();}});` it's more elegant and you can add whatever you want to that function.. :P

Comment: Thats something im ideally looking for. Can't seem to get that bit up and running though. Copied what you put and used an alert, but it's not called.

Comment: Hmm...that's odd...should work just fine..well, the ajaxflagmenu isn't quite using the ajax call at its best :) ...to avoid further complication, I suggest using the method that worked so far...eventually create a global function with the code you want to execute and call that function at the end of the ajax update...

Comment: One last question Catalin. I've managed to get it working to run the JotForm.init() using a new function. Is there anyway I can run a specific function for a specific page? I'm looking to make an ajax form submit, and obviously each menu will have a different form with different vars.

Comment: I need more details..I don't understand how the menu thing is connected to the form and the submitting of the form :).. you could use a switch in the function and execute diferent functions based on a global var you declare for each page...that's all i can give at this moment :)

Comment: At the moment the AjaxFlagMenu has 5 options that pull in the html from 5 different files. Each menu option has a form, its basically allowing a user to edit their profile information. What I need to do (now I am able to validate each form using the function containing `JotForm.init()`) is submit that form using AJAX. What I'm trying to do is collect the form values off each page to pass them through using jQuery using the normal AJAX functions. Just need to work out how to get the values from the loaded page, that could be any page out of the 5.

Comment: Give the form the same id..something like id="jotFormId" and then serialize the form (don't know the syntax for jqery..I mostly use prototype..should be something like $("#jotFormId").serialize()) and pass the serialized data to the ajax request. Add a hidden input in the form that tells you where you are something like <input type="hidden" name="section" value="inHere" /> then, in the server side script use a switch ($_REQUEST['section'])..case ("inHere")..do the mango :)

Comment: I think you need a return false at the end so the form will not actually submit...

Comment: I've actually put an alert in there and it's not calling. Can you call a function inside a function like that? So I assume the submit button will bind when the external page has loaded?

Comment: uh..there is a problem with form submitting and triggers... form.submit() doesn't trigger the onsubmit event and things :) why not add event on the button and put a button type button <button type="button" onclick="blah blah">Click me</button>

Comment: Would the noConflict stuff mess around with why I can't get the form to do anything expect, even `return false;` in the onclick isn't working at the moment.

Also, should the function that I'm calling (as mentioned in the AjaxFlagMenu.js) be writen inside the $(document).ready() bit or outside? I can't get my functions to call when inside the .ready.

Comment: Fixed it! Had to rewrite some functions inside the dom ready. Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the JotForm Iframe Code instead. Here is how you can get it. Open your form on the JotForm Form Builder:

1. Open "Setup & Share" tab on toolbar,
2. Click on "Share Form"
3. Click on "Advanced Options"
4. Click on "iFrame Code"and copy the form code to your site.

Comment: Doing that though, as far as I can see, gives me no options on where the form posts to. It also relies on the JotForm servers to be online. If they go down, a large part of our site goes too.